# Convert cURL to Java for SOAP Call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, curl, soap

Im implementing a SOAP web service and it is working with a cURL call. I implemented following [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/). The service is working with the following command:

```
curl --header "content-type: text/xml" -d @request.xml http://localhost:8080/ws
```

But of course this action has to be free from command prompt and be able to be called whenever necessary, so I want to relate this service to an action when a method is called for example.

So far I found from internet

```
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/ws";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

I assume it should be a POST method but how do I add the "request.xml" and "--header"? What command will finalize the cURL call? Or am I doing this totally wrong and the long way, is there an easier way?

PS: I already have a web service running and Im using Eclipse Oxygen.

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  But "best practice" is: 1) get the SOAP service's "WSDL", 2) use an IDE (like Eclipse or NetBeans) to generate a "Web service client", then 3) use the auto-generated code to make the web service call.  Here's an example: http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html

Comment: I have a wsdl file and service running, Im using Eclipse Oxygen

Comment: Good - it sounds like you're already 80% (or more) of the way there. Just use Eclipse/JEE edition to generate a "top down web service client project", per the link above.  This tutorial might also help: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-jse/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below lines to your code at the end, it will do the JOB.

```
OutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("request.xml")));

    //reading file and writing to URL
    System.out.println("Request:-");
    String st;
    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.print(st);
        wr.write(st.getBytes());
    }

    //Flush&close the writing to URL.
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String output;

    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(output);
    }

    in.close();


    // printing result from response
    System.out.println("Response:-" + response.toString());
```

Comment: Im getting the following error "The constructor BufferedReader(FileReader) is undefined" for the second line with "request.xml"

Comment: Add full path `@request.xml` file location in your code there.

Comment: The file is in the project folder at highest level. so I assume giving it plain request.xml should work.

Comment: "request.xml" is actually a string, I cant even compile because of the error.

Comment: It worked thank you very much!!! I just moved `new File("requestPDF.xml")` up and the nit complained about File library, I imported it and then it worked. 20+ lines for a single simple line! Isnt it too much? Isnt there a shorter/simpler way? PS: Can I do the same call from Frontend html? I have a spring-boot application.

Answer (score 1):

While `HttpURLConnection` can be used for this purpose, `SOAPConnection` was designed for situations where there is not a WSDL.

The code below is much simpler:

```
SOAPConnection conn = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();

SOAPMessage msg =
        MessageFactory.newInstance()
            .createMessage(null, Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("request.xml")));

SOAPMessage resp = conn.call(msg, "http://localhost:8080/ws");

resp.writeTo(System.out);
```